# How to sync tables in different databases using Percona Toolkit, but only inserts

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization

I have two databases, one large (test2) and one small (test1), and they have course tables. I want to synchronize them, but so that only inserts work on the tables. Update and delete did not work during sync.

This is `courses` table in `test1` database.

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
| 1 | one   |
| 2 | two   |
| 3 | three |
| 4 | four  |
| 5 | five  |
+----+------+
```

And this is `courses` table in `test2` database.

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
| 1 | one   |
| 2 | two   |
| 3 | three |
| 4 | four  |
| 5 | five  |
| 6 | six   |
| 7 | seven |
| 8 | eight |
+----+------+
```

And now i deleted 5th row from `courses` table in `test1` database.
Then i insert 2 new rows

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | one   |
|  2 | two   |
|  3 | three |
|  4 | four  |
|  6 | nine  |
|  7 | ten   |
+----+-------+
```

as you can see there is no 5th row in the table and there are 2 new rows.

And now I want to synchronize these two tables (small to large) using [pt-table-sync](https://docs.percona.com/percona-toolkit/pt-table-sync.html) but only those lines that were inserted and I expect something like this result.

(`test2` database)

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | one   |
|  2 | two   |
|  3 | three |
|  4 | four  |
|  5 | five  |
|  6 | six   |
|  7 | seven |
|  8 | eight |
|  9 | nine  |
| 10 | ten   |
+----+-------+
```

as you can see as a result of synchronization I only received 2 new rows and did not remove the 5th line.

**How can I synchronize tables so that it turns out like this?**

Comment: I assume by saying _"Percona Toolkit"_, you mean [`pt-table-sync`](https://docs.percona.com/percona-toolkit/pt-table-sync.html). What exactly did you try? What did or did not work as you expected? What is the DDL (`SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name;`) and size of these two tables? What exactly do you want to achieve? Add some sample data ([markdown tables](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables)) to your question (only a handful of rows for each table) and the desired outcome.

Comment: I edited the question, you can watch it.
Thank you

Comment: What you describe is not synchronisation. A sync would copy the values from source `row (id:6)` to target `row (id:6)`. You are saying that if `row (id:6)` in source has a different `name` value to target `row (id:6)`, then create new `row (id:<auto_inc>, name:name)` in target. I don't think (I may be wrong) you will be able to do that with any synchronisation tool, as they rely on a unique key being shared by the two (or more) tables. You will have to write your own update logic in your language of choice.